# Should i via shield a usb 2.0 trace?

Tags: pcb-design, usb, emc, pcb-layers

im looking into designing some usb 2.0 devices and have been wondering about how far id need to go to ensure that for good practice that it would ideally pass any test thrown at it.

I use altium designer so im able to setup the impedance profile in the stackup and have it calculate all the figures i need with respect to the fab houses stack up.

my stackup is signal / gnd / gnd / signal with filled ground pour on the signal layers as well.

from what i understand
-keeping the groundpour at a distance (3W rule) from the usb lines would be ideal (prevent change of impedance).
-ensure no other traces pass through them on any layers below.

What i'm uncertain about is whether i should have a via shield around the lines and if not what cases need shielding like that ?

EDIT: I wasnt clear it is USB HIGHSPEED.

[image: pcb updated]
[image: bottom layer]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: On a side note: This looks like a USB-C connector. If so, you should pull-down CC1 and CC2 to ground, each one with a 5.1kΩ resistor.

Comment: @Codo Oh ok, if you dont mind me asking where did you find out about that ?

Comment: if i interpret your layout correctly you have the diode array right at the connector and the CMC further down the line. I would put the CMC right at the connector so CM noise has no trace length from where it cam couple to other things. the diodes can be behind the CMC. also don't make trace stubs to the diode but run the traces through the two pads. the short "impedance mismatch" from widened trace pair won't matter if it is short. The stubs are worse

Comment: Oh sorry i should post the schematic. thanks for the tip il fix the stubs, and il also post the schematic.

Comment: updated the question with the new images!

Comment: Regarding pull-down resistors, see e.g. [Converting Existing USB Designs to Support Type-C Connections](https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/converting-existing-designs.html), chapter "Converting USB 2.0 Device and Host SoCs to USB Type-C". Before USB-C, there were separate plugs for host and device. There was no ambiguity about the role. With USB-C, it is physically possible to connect host to host, device to device and to even swap roles dynamically. To be compliant, a USB device at least needs to the pull-down on CC1/2.

Comment: You submitted the schematics for USB FS (12Mbps) device. This R-C stuff won't work for HS (480Mbps) connections. For FS,  none of your layout concerns have much of significance.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Was that referring to me or codo ?

Comment: Is this your schematics, right?

Comment: yes, sorry i thought you may be referring to the link codo has mentioned.
what would your advice be on that front then for HS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high speed USB does require a bit of care which means:

- length matching D+/- traces!
- filter common mode noise from D+/- traces e.g. with a small CMC and bonding the USB shield to chassis ground
- stick to the required impedance
- keep sufficient distance with any other signals (3H minimum)

Via fencing won't hurt, but it *must not* be to close. otherwise you will cause a similar unintentional reduction of line impedance as with pouring GND beside the traces as you mentioned in your question. Closer than 3 H would be not a good choice unless you can properly recalculate trace widths for proper impedance.

If you have tons of free space around D+/-, then go for it, but it is not definitely necessary. Keeping your distance to those traces and filtering should be the standard and first things to do.

It is fine to cross the D+/- lines with other things on L4. they are well shielded from one another and they don't even use the same reference planes if you have double ground planes.

Comment: Corrent me if im wrong but from what i've read isnt the CMC typically a last ditch effort to pass testing whilst also degrading the signal, if not which CMC would you typically use ?

Will do, id completely forgotten to add length matching as a rule.

whats your opinion on the stackup ?

Comment: @lolbardsnin there are CMC designed to be used with USB 2.0 so I guess their influence on signal integrity would be minimal. but your are correct. if you have good chassis ground available and bond the USB shield well to chassis ground, you probably get hardly any advantage from the CMC. I like this stack very much as described in my comment to Enrico. but I wouldn't pour L1 and L4 with ground. Instead, you can use free area for power pours to create planar capacitance, especially for fast chips like the USB chip. but also power pours must keep distance to impedance controlled lines.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer my question ! il fix up the pours and properly sort out the remaining issues. What il do regarding the CMC is add the footprint and if its needed it's needed (not that im doing any testing).

Comment: @lolbardsnin from memory, the CMC that I used in USB 2 is about the size of two 0402 or 0603 resistors, so if you shape the pads accordingly, you could always populate it with 0R resistors.

Comment: ah ok, thanks will do !!